# Jquery in Customer Portal in Salesforce

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, styles, salesforce

I am trying to use a Visualforce page with Jquery UI and Salesforce Customer Portal. But Jquery UI is overriding all Standard Salesforce stylesheet. How Can i Prevent that.? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you ask this question on [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com)? Community is dedicated to salesforce.